# How to deploy Gatsby site with webhook from Github to CloudWays?

Tags: git, gatsby, web-hosting, cloudways

I want to host my website build in Gatsby on CloudWays. Is there such an option for continuous deployment?
There is an option to deploy code via Git and fetch the repo. But for Gatsby, there's another step involved by doing 'gatsby build'.
Is there a way to pull from master and then run a build command, whenever the master branch is updated?

I know there's Netlify and has this already build in, but I have a CloudWays hosting and was just wondering if this is possible to set up at all.

Answer (score 0):

As **CloudWays recommends** **DeployBot** ([see here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/automate-deployment-using-deploybot/)), you can use that for your requirements, more specifically, you can provide the set of commands that you need to execute with `gatsby build` for automated deployment while setting up the DeployBot.

You need to review following references: [Getting Started With DeployBot](https://deploybot.com/guides-code-deployment-tools/getting-started-with-deploybot) and [Building assets with Grunt](https://deploybot.com/guides-code-deployment-tools/building-assets-with-grunt-or-gulp-during-deployment).
Note: You can replace the Grunt tool with your **preferred Build Tool** to achieve the required automated deployment process.